# How to drop all views in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created lot of tables and views in path (called it parlgov)
[image]

I want to either delete all the tables and views in this Schema (or called path) or **preferable to only delete all** the view and leave the tables.

I have tried manually delete by drop view view's name which is not efficient.

I am wondering if there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Write a script like :
    Select 'Drop view '||viewname ||';' from user_views.

Comment: use the o/p to drop the views.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? oracle, mySql, postgre? You can create a loop then drop each of them.

Comment: postgre, Could you give me some example?

Comment: what is the o/p ?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a simple anonymous PL/pgSQL block:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_stmt text;
begin
  for l_rec in (select schemaname, viewname
                from pg_views
                where schemaname = 'parlgov')
  loop
    l_stmt := format('drop view if exists %I.%I cascade', l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.viewname);
    raise notice 'Dropping %', l_stmt;
    execute l_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: I do not see where the l_vrec and vrec variables come from. Shouldn't they be l_rec? Works perfectly for me by replacing "l_vrec.schemaname, vrec.viewname" by "l_rec.schemaname, l_rec.viewname"

Answer (score -1):

```
select 'DROP VIEW '||viewname||';' FROM  pg_views where schemaname='parlgov';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 'DROP VIEW ' || table_name || ';' 
FROM information_schema.views 
WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
AND table_name !~ '^pg_';
```

Comment: This lacks explanations; besides the request was to drop only the views in a certain schema. Also, dropping the view may fail if other objects depend on it.

Comment: That's just a copy/paste job from another question